# Trying to reduce expression

Tags: definite-integrals

I am working through a derivation in Nielsen and Chuang's 2016 text book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, and I have not been able to reproduce a result they get for Equation 5.34.  While the text is not a math text, this question is. They have an integral
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{e-1}^{2^{t-1}-1}dl\frac{1}{l^2}=\frac{1}{2(e-1)} $$
with $ t $ an integer and $ e $ a real number.  I have not beeen able to reproduce this result.  By hand I get
$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{e-1}-\frac{1}{2^{t-1}-1}\right) $.  Can someone help me to reduce this to the given result?  Or is there some sort of limiting argument? Thank you!

Comment: As you mentioned, perhaps they are taking a limit as $t\to\infty$.  Any suggestion of that in the problem or the accompanying text?

Comment: It simply says that $ t $ is a $ t $-bit binary expansion.  Maybe a large $ t $ is implied here?

Comment: It says that $0 \leq 2^t\delta \leq 1$ but I have no idea what delta implies in this context.

Comment: $ \delta $  is the difference between the measured state $ \phi $ and $ 2^{-t} $. The goal is to find the best $ t $-bit approximation $ b/2^t $ where $ b $ is an integer.  I guess that might imply a large $ t $.

Comment: I guess the only thing that makes sense here is a limit for large $ t $.  Thanks for the help!